# How can I get all new or changed files?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, groovy, dvcs

I want to make a script that uses all new/changed files in some folder.
Intellij can tell changed (blue) and new (green) files from the unchanged ones. So, they must be foundable.

How can I distinct them in a Gradle task?

Comment: Doesn't intellij just check with `git`?

Comment: In my case with Mercurial, but yes, it does. And the result of the check surely is available somehow.

Comment: `hg status`?  In the output, `M` is modified, and `A` is added

Comment: And just process the ouput in a task and do what needs to be done

Comment: @tim_yates Oh, excellent, just what I wanted. And I have found already "vcs" object in the idea model. So, the task can be even made universal - for any vcs. Could you, please put your comment as an answer?

Comment: @ToYonos I see, of course, I only expected some special object from idea model doing that.